# fitting a model to a density distribution in R

Tags: r, probability-density, model-fitting, function-fitting

I am trying to figure out how to fit a published model to a dataset.

Details of the model and equation are shown here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhdQZ.png)

I have a dataframe of apparent diffusion (D*) from the equation in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhdQZ.png) and also the number of steps (n).

I need to fit my data distribution to this model [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcqmv.png)

Are D and x in this equation the same? This is causing me some confusion.

The dataframe:

```
n   D
6   16.1693
29  6.95744
23  7.66054
7   24.6076
14  8.88381
11  5.89875
33  8.16877
9   18.8922
10  15.2757
6   12.2641
9   4.2205
22  8.57661
5   2.43809
6   12.2284
9   3.5797
7   16.3401
4   9.23816
4   4.34992
10  5.77003
9   4.43707
8   3.90128
21  7.1065
15  9.08997
34  1.56546
5   15.2622
10  5.19957
5   5.86306
16  7.82247
12  8.11728
63  6.94382
19  10.6853
4   22.634
14  4.64683
15  8.83135
10  11.8849
20  9.88979
7   4.53146
4   5.58701
9   6.46933
5   3.92932
5   13.2794
9   21.9321
17  14.4281
5   4.33572
37  4.27755
11  4.43083
19  6.82866
9   14.927
29  4.39848
6   3.56756
7   5.00384
15  5.41498
7   9.67496
8   8.90499
41  5.59504
5   5.30941
11  4.05351
8   14.1295
5   6.94491
7   4.53821
6   7.43668
14  5.10146
4   18.2141
8   3.21058
12  6.26661
19  5.53264
7   9.14843
9   7.86705
13  7.79207
10  16.0144
37  5.61845
24  5.45841
8   3.72465
6   9.15419
8   9.50775
4   7.2576
5   6.8974
4   9.90056
5   1.76761
4   1.28818
67  9.4782
4   5.88126
8   11.8879
17  8.64635
10  7.49368
6   7.97186
39  6.78984
27  4.6375
6   7.21579
4   1.87345
22  7.53034
13  9.77943
5   7.02081
11  15.3463
8   1.42405
10  10.4216
8   9.32649
4   4.86869
4   8.69224
6   7.2981
5   6.32456
27  5.23167
8   4.26364
4   5.89355
6   15.0599
17  3.79605
75  5.10882
6   10.9887
26  4.29229
8   19.6015
8   7.4532
14  7.77257
5   4.02287
4   8.1798
15  4.50524
4   3.52175
6   3.77109
4   16.1092
5   10.2184
4   1.31019
7   10.9105
16  5.54095
7   8.26732
4   5.46121
7   3.14528
5   2.9076
7   5.38087
13  10.0418
8   6.00922
4   6.38978
4   1.16043
6   7.11854
18  6.61809
5   18.4267
8   9.4416
4   6.34204
4   3.97339
8   9.47709
25  5.72887
17  4.38445
4   9.39688
10  5.1629
6   5.14524
7   6.63644
7   6.61286
4   3.9732
5   5.45305
6   8.66114
10  13.8499
8   8.3179
7   6.27027
39  10.5038
4   11.675
4   2.10659
7   8.05701
8   9.1416
28  10.3282
8   6.09853
5   10.4296
49  6.73058
7   8.08364
5   5.56982
8   7.99871
11  9.07808
14  8.74915
9   3.05946
5   9.02942
24  4.65335
8   5.28659
10  11.7005
9   7.9019
13  1.7073
5   3.98097
4   7.1036
8   4.44103
8   10.5211
22  8.36037
6   16.5121
6   3.36161
7   3.85915
9   14.2648
13  13.9042
8   11.3231
8   4.24438
4   9.2
11  2.77842
4   8.07942
5   5.06842
7   10.0444
4   4.62739
4   9.07243
12  3.80894
45  5.08952
21  6.94786
6   12.6898
4   13.9838
4   6.27831
13  10.8506
4   17.543
6   14.3726
37  4.29764
11  2.84348
7   7.84218
7   1.62582
4   4.25611
4   11.8145
12  7.61603
7   13.6282
4   4.44655
8   16.8558
4   11.2504
4   0.940673
4   3.34161
16  3.00202
14  11.938
26  7.59963
7   5.14337
7   5.2484
5   4.44258
13  2.98905
5   5.10393
5   2.09328
37  3.90394
22  6.01075
17  3.9939
6   19.4055
10  8.05424
55  10.109
4   3.55426
11  2.94729
11  3.80218
6   10.8055
18  6.56886
8   11.0226
6   6.82045
4   2.42667
5   10.8811
18  5.87932
13  3.21932
4   3.36937
20  3.00249
8   6.54755
4   17.1626
7   9.7982
6   4.922
7   2.4292
4   3.74126
5   11.6342
12  9.81202
4   10.1603
4   6.64092
4   4.19567
4   4.72367
6   5.27054
4   3.61887
5   15.066
4   7.80564
4   0.994988
6   6.56088
7   3.02964
11  5.32366
29  8.41929
11  11.1174
4   20.5039
9   9.07833
25  9.91062
6   11.7417
6   5.18911
4   9.01824
45  8.09247
15  4.0735
12  19.8334
7   9.37491
7   9.68244
4   4.10823
7   6.03255
13  8.94892
6   20.4803
17  9.15187
4   41.0176
9   17.0149
15  5.91976
19  9.52719
7   13.8433
10  9.18984
18  10.3163
53  5.11534
12  5.64626
5   17.7302
25  9.71165
5   15.529
17  9.0897
15  10.383
5   4.60562
6   10.9851
7   7.48659
8   4.77201
7   10.4422
16  9.41269
19  7.46288
7   5.29129
8   12.6097
22  9.28684
74  9.29769
5   7.88201
6   7.6608
29  5.01021
8   10.8468
4   10.493
5   5.51872
8   4.00857
5   5.3458
6   7.53767
15  4.03411
32  12.4305
7   15.1404
11  3.89022
4   4.80646
7   12.8567
8   5.19944
18  12.2352
25  5.82377
4   6.82975
4   17.1336
11  3.01867
30  6.0417
6   7.5281
32  6.61119
11  5.75534
14  6.25002
40  9.02338
6   9.8725
36  8.97259
5   15.1208
27  12.6702
5   6.95754
13  11.1277
19  8.36837
6   6.0491
6   14.9543
9   6.33145
32  6.15491
9   7.69184
4   6.17417
8   12.5346
7   4.83411
4   0.886051
14  9.63098
4   4.27818
19  4.71805
25  9.41496
5   4.8577
6   5.43837
51  7.92163
39  4.27369
5   7.25765
4   3.39691
37  10.279
5   1.45927
11  3.73836
6   6.37452
6   9.58176
69  3.28546
4   4.44583
7   10.1013
10  4.86906
7   8.64699
4   9.77237
7   4.26821
5   9.10079
19  8.37994
5   18.0182
5   4.39684
4   4.80113
8   6.26875
5   19.2315
54  1.31136
33  6.49233
12  7.4871
9   4.54722
15  4.87368
8   8.14971
5   7.73712
11  4.88992
20  4.57845
4   7.51247
8   1.96748
19  6.29791
8   6.74184
9   9.57862
5   9.83782
7   11.3725
6   4.42387
10  7.06773
6   11.8456
32  5.79843
13  13.2486
13  7.0247
36  7.21733
6   12.7207
10  10.0221
12  6.14754
7   6.03929
40  8.57295
6   11.7657
38  7.99936
4   9.50411
4   14.496
35  8.14862
10  11.5238
4   9.42894
11  6.75271
8   12.3427
21  9.90872
5   19.3727
4   10.579
13  5.90007
4   11.4053
4   13.817
11  11.4348
4   11.6535
11  9.44845
4   6.04428
5   7.42656
4   5.17453
14  7.40451
5   1.69463
4   8.15573
9   9.86957
11  11.4412
7   9.51392
16  6.16268
29  11.407
18  6.67891
16  5.23633
16  14.3687
6   4.88755
53  6.12915
8   8.55567
16  6.76427
5   7.01236
13  9.59372
4   10.7199
5   15.8954
12  1.38346
19  9.7957
4   18.0668
10  12.7076
7   6.69635
10  8.19132
25  8.59163
5   24.893
4   12.0637
20  13.1037
5   13.2987
11  9.51644
9   4.72763
5   20.8506
6   11.21
8   8.19004
6   24.9133
13  10.3163
4   12.0486
4   5.05456
4   7.29071
6   2.54061
4   4.77332
7   6.60557
4   5.18637
7   3.80679
26  10.258
15  4.49815
4   18.1461
4   9.7945
4   10.1782
10  13.2135
13  10.0199
5   19.2617
5   3.9299
6   1.49049
19  11.7899
24  1.92224
6   4.27185
11  9.19738
4   22.0556
5   17.8052
32  6.4669
9   12.5228
4   2.9297
12  5.11769
4   8.19326
6   14.357
9   12.334
5   16.5749
10  4.01052
16  14.6244
19  5.51143
5   21.2266
20  3.81325
5   15.9669
4   2.68911
7   1.44358
4   2.87054
15  6.80376
4   1.82632
6   4.21866
7   15.0345
4   4.49516
5   8.39518
4   3.69212
7   9.75684
7   15.4615
10  18.8199
5   18.8258
10  3.36979
13  7.33419
6   17.0571
26  1.53175
9   9.9712
4   10.3649
38  0.740367
4   1.29965
8   2.09779
7   16.0598
7   3.41323
11  3.72058
6   4.00974
5   8.23234
4   6.61152
19  7.07587
7   11.4555
6   7.08395
4   10.972
23  0.917861
4   3.14026
7   4.22944
6   3.52015
13  5.96351
5   10.4885
8   1.23162
4   9.62736
8   5.63199
5   9.69307
4   6.09755
9   11.6543
4   1.27177
5   16.434
4   5.89135
11  7.45377
4   4.71543
8   7.15632
6   12.4733
4   7.30201
4   4.03364
4   12.2982
8   6.60874
18  8.95991
5   16.3711
6   8.3649
12  1.00274
28  7.70672
4   13.0514
8   7.89006
14  8.69344
13  5.71736
50  0.870717
6   5.6773
4   2.53118
12  9.18717
4   13.743
4   7.63913
8   6.71842
4   10.5403
5   9.84237
21  8.68478
4   7.18612
7   1.06827
8   0.751419
6   9.63001
4   9.1629
8   7.10638
4   3.78854
6   6.03218
5   4.09128
5   6.40873
8   5.67051
5   8.13922
7   9.8616
8   3.0221
22  6.18295
11  3.05981
16  4.56805
5   4.03661
66  6.15321
22  5.69653
28  13.8167
18  7.74219
4   2.93453
5   8.91556
6   3.67423
21  6.6657
4   4.82726
4   11.8191
4   9.79784
12  14.2138
25  5.97174
15  13.5428
8   6.80563
21  11.8932
6   14.6238
11  13.9869
52  4.2076
30  9.04408
4   12.8902
19  12.9141
8   2.48893
16  13.4498
4   17.5283
4   7.01612
11  8.76975
15  8.21731
4   7.88112
16  6.95465
6   4.00958
9   5.46003
4   8.24018
5   4.73601
22  7.0614
8   2.77676
13  3.16918
5   4.94642
24  12.0763
4   21.812
5   6.47157
7   17.0296
11  8.46085
13  10.8281
5   20.0598
10  6.53189
9   9.78346
6   9.00286
5   12.1462
32  6.18333
21  6.86122
6   5.47728
16  6.48787
21  6.24357
25  4.21758
8   0.806496
15  3.10368
12  10.4091
18  11.4366
9   6.2496
12  21.033
20  7.27648
8   10.7495
7   6.30541
4   1.25707
6   10.8126
21  11.6242
7   15.4946
9   9.24556
7   1.02894
4   10.1415
5   6.15597
4   7.75065
6   6.21703
5   2.95157
16  12.3517
24  6.18562
5   13.4244
19  8.34601
27  10.4223
4   5.66702
11  9.49525
5   15.7393
5   7.25596
6   3.7934
16  14.3714
11  17.4736
5   10.9433
4   8.8336
6   4.4724
9   4.94749
33  13.3733
4   9.9071
40  7.68868
7   15.1338
5   10.1261
10  13.2432
7   7.31594
6   3.65833
7   7.24156
5   4.34046
4   8.41281
4   5.21182
8   6.9173
4   13.2239
8   9.27886
8   7.46864
6   11.2666
10  5.00644
17  10.4805
4   6.07913
8   17.7638
4   2.60227
4   6.31402
7   7.84318
11  7.34386
7   5.68347
33  9.25309
6   12.2509
4   9.0981
14  5.07898
8   18.5004
12  15.2972
10  19.0073
4   6.60009
23  6.66052
4   11.1979
4   14.2767
4   4.65281
8   17.7194
6   7.71884
5   11.1417
8   16.0098
8   15.4062
4   1.79562
5   1.97934
5   2.50545
6   11.6727
4   5.20648
4   6.09141
4   9.60115
5   5.8942
10  8.69295
48  6.78206
7   16.3256
4   3.61786
5   3.96036
9   10.9963
10  5.13205
4   3.44912
6   7.54323
9   10.6859
5   3.75914
6   11.9806
4   12.0293
11  6.95981
9   10.7666
4   6.84392
4   3.65086
5   5.60636
10  10.64
5   13.3392
5   7.24023
5   3.13008
5   2.2695
9   13.159
4   6.40173
4   7.53556
4   5.24271
9   7.63686
4   8.55155
6   0.794395
12  0.774572
4   12.2137
4   5.07304
4   12.6834
6   2.51888
4   7.33227
4   0.986925
4   1.70198
16  9.28519
9   1.39987
17  2.91594
16  4.2964
7   8.99818
9   6.25679
25  8.93453
17  5.90314
16  6.80086
24  10.2752
16  6.28381
16  5.15422
5   18.1131
9   3.16139
6   8.04448
18  4.76119
9   6.81272
35  5.42931
21  18.2357
6   15.1372
7   6.99942
27  5.41456
21  5.28753
9   13.016
5   4.63557
30  5.15181
10  1.23659
4   9.02225
7   6.95968
9   9.88862
7   7.36041
13  6.98269
4   9.36711
25  10.8892
12  6.76683
44  5.07632
6   10.7961
29  8.59522
5   2.81338
4   6.28351
12  1.59647
5   5.16854
7   14.4913
8   3.97279
19  5.20089
4   1.96562
10  12.1537
4   15.3751
11  8.56482
33  6.64277
25  14.3409
7   16.7304
62  6.58747
4   2.42415
19  2.97408
20  3.60803
8   6.41198
12  5.37805
27  4.50585
4   21.1342
21  6.20593
5   31.3684
15  5.39253
5   5.47974
4   6.00669
47  5.71607
8   8.44368
49  5.7375
14  3.26521
10  6.21576
6   10.4837
7   5.24993
4   9.37565
22  5.34031
5   4.16423
5   2.28298
51  8.15904
5   19.6947
5   0.80783
8   8.06952
70  4.96765
6   14.0349
9   25.9748
4   3.7916
14  11.8718
5   7.06589
18  11.4422
8   5.59955
8   2.94877
10  10.992
31  8.48155
11  9.13858
5   5.24694
10  8.233
10  5.15933
5   5.13126
5   14.4717
4   3.0615
5   8.6877
9   10.4637
6   8.48307
11  5.84917
4   2.99477
6   8.59874
4   4.40055
10  6.35706
6   9.94606
8   0.977799
15  8.11636
10  3.25845
109 5.49411
8   2.32721
16  4.06833
19  2.10977
4   12.4984
7   36.9302
4   14.2224
4   6.87563
4   9.845
8   7.98671
9   8.97332
19  2.35613
7   7.49985
4   19.473
12  7.3042
11  4.04249
20  5.40606
7   3.74967
19  7.38808
17  4.79346
6   5.86213
38  10.4957
24  8.36563
18  2.84539
6   3.29085
8   4.9111
20  9.77446
5   14.169
17  4.13249
4   9.60407
18  7.58892
42  3.72497
9   6.91983
15  5.80645
4   18.5483
7   5.06625
42  5.59
29  12.5507
6   7.95824
11  11.4407
8   9.20384
4   6.70884
7   6.50464
5   4.37398
19  7.748
32  10.3775
6   6.63337
14  4.74974
7   15.4182
6   6.70726
5   6.69711
10  12.5341
4   21.0316
41  5.89733
21  2.41973
8   8.19385
26  8.1546
4   10.6347
16  5.8739
4   7.92148
9   9.24801
6   9.27338
31  5.60478
4   4.35284
8   10.701
8   4.36121
6   1.31401
4   19.5421
6   10.9634
4   6.13838
23  4.13052
5   13.2386
10  6.40519
53  6.63273
11  5.49061
6   3.9007
17  5.03859
5   8.30389
14  18.5018
28  8.8984
5   1.81496
48  8.91168
4   3.75839
21  2.90767
8   7.22742
33  8.15415
53  11.4095
8   18.7344
5   10.577
4   5.09826
5   2.07749
8   10.8144
7   10.2127
9   8.4347
10  10.0349
4   6.15027
6   2.28599
7   7.93572
9   7.34118
14  6.09031
7   7.3006
45  7.09423
4   1.33645
8   14.4526
4   7.08032
11  4.79024
4   12.0431
5   2.57087
16  4.86222
6   4.78049
6   3.96594
7   2.57981
41  3.7921
14  3.90545
24  3.87089
8   8.63085
12  19.1375
20  7.70843
47  7.20331
5   5.91793
5   9.86039
4   4.64594
10  5.77038
9   2.34492
38  7.51938
9   4.80303
12  14.0615
8   7.28326
19  9.66733
47  5.75326
5   3.38573
9   5.44017
24  6.87599
10  9.47107
12  6.79666
5   1.75299
38  7.69266
15  5.61026
7   13.5915
4   3.11537
12  6.39935
4   7.12639
8   1.2571
4   9.68493
18  3.9985
8   6.09214
9   13.1175
6   1.582
6   9.19583
56  5.94625
25  4.32547
4   6.1255
9   12.1471
9   3.53177
9   8.62854
22  10.6622
5   7.98789
7   9.76413
4   17.8281
65  5.71063
7   0.890085
29  3.80254
12  3.5459
20  6.15626
4   20.0254
5   8.32468
5   29.742
22  6.81443
4   2.47438
42  6.77664
18  10.6616
15  8.05075
4   9.02896
7   7.48956
6   2.91088
4   3.03396
10  7.53855
14  2.43732
10  9.00266
22  15.1172
4   2.10672
4   4.49333
7   3.15671
38  6.92405
8   13.0506
6   8.69566
10  7.03648
5   2.00527
6   0.954127
10  8.09208
4   4.96376
4   4.43958
14  5.58138
5   3.09601
11  3.5262
4   8.33322
6   11.5486
18  7.57425
5   2.83417
6   9.43153
4   0.918853
5   7.75331
4   3.19178
11  1.5561
13  8.39383
24  5.49064
5   4.88094
4   3.34757
4   5.12223
5   5.15522
25  8.43619
4   4.85253
4   35.8834
9   8.92566
5   16.3607
16  1.59487
7   23.8568
11  6.39793
4   13.6148
9   15.175
24  3.4752
8   17.818
18  11.6706
7   5.28669
33  4.91901
7   16.4209
7   11.1932
5   5.37852
8   6.68451
23  1.25288
4   11.253
16  14.2972
4   9.7042
11  6.75403
25  7.5279
5   20.385
15  14.051
5   13.0078
5   15.922
5   21.4825
8   2.09958
20  6.61385
4   1.41148
6   10.5498
7   3.93411
10  6.45799
15  8.61957
39  8.69927
6   10.745
13  5.41675
13  8.20857
6   14.7968
6   9.1487
4   13.636
5   21.4302
7   11.2109
5   6.34895
41  6.75438
4   8.76922
12  6.51222
4   26.8182
4   7.27081
4   8.40243
4   6.30526
5   7.61186
4   3.36989
4   2.92409
9   2.02215
7   2.40541
5   6.2039
16  5.02525
5   5.88596
7   4.80479
12  5.49408
10  8.70615
4   4.89584
11  6.04424
5   2.96187
4   5.31255
8   4.94725
8   14.5442
7   18.3454
9   15.0843
6   7.58322
10  4.6386
11  4.93008
10  6.58939
10  6.11791
4   7.74141
10  11.7516
4   12.3938
4   5.4703
6   2.49468
15  8.38246
4   8.3817
5   9.60288
22  11.7374
4   2.43527
5   10.3144
7   9.08492
4   3.18577
5   8.87359
4   10.5922
6   6.76757
5   5.52752
4   7.58328
5   4.05443
6   4.20954
8   14.4161
6   5.29189
29  5.52229
12  7.09305
16  6.37976
29  9.48505
5   19.3982
7   9.79444
5   8.1576
14  11.8035
5   8.43284
6   5.29265
11  7.02019
8   13.534
13  7.13543
27  5.71252
6   13.6545
8   8.04559
4   7.76255
4   8.08626
4   4.16599
8   3.77822
9   8.8568
23  10.7367
8   8.2191
5   1.74918
8   7.63465
13  9.32419
6   8.79706
5   15.4076
7   17.8238
34  10.2077
6   13.8557
12  8.07164
13  14.1308
12  17.0733
30  11.0101
13  10.0491
22  6.18584
9   4.20852
5   2.65289
17  8.94523
8   5.50482
6   9.53493
7   24.591
13  6.32331
19  11.3894
14  10.1854
4   12.3948
16  6.95055
13  6.17838
5   3.8309
13  8.73328
4   23.4474
14  13.4613
4   13.3889
20  9.6924
8   5.18591
8   17.0651
18  9.52647
4   6.32325
7   29.7699
6   27.8564
8   14.4558
8   5.96027
34  7.37892
6   6.57987
9   13.0858
19  10.6525
10  13.784
36  3.44008
10  4.98896
4   10.5359
4   5.80166
8   7.54147
21  1.14524
16  11.7418
8   3.41447
7   5.28356
10  5.5154
5   2.77046
9   6.69647
33  9.50621
14  6.7445
5   4.51881
8   11.509
4   16.4914
4   9.5769
8   4.15454
7   12.4834
39  7.09677
4   4.52977
9   16.6967
5   3.47655
9   8.80103
5   2.4592
40  8.09468
9   5.35303
8   6.09031
10  7.09897
21  3.46474
21  8.12347
11  11.7323
6   12.7858
7   7.12583
4   8.68419
5   8.87775
4   8.78327
28  7.22714
5   8.93233
19  7.91032
5   8.4773
5   10.0489
22  5.03526
5   9.64074
4   9.25775
4   17.4061
4   7.67731
8   6.36563
7   7.6863
6   2.00972
10  11.559
21  9.80919
19  4.61711
5   13.1991
4   16.1863
13  8.52632
13  11.713
4   6.39226
5   7.43297
17  3.0411
6   6.13122
6   6.64945
11  6.8625
5   16.6535
6   5.92925
9   9.09044
4   5.8015
4   11.7663
55  6.83198
6   17.7091
4   6.84847
10  6.96107
4   12.2952
7   15.7357
7   16.9079
5   4.77904
4   4.92745
4   12.5846
6   12.1043
15  9.16974
5   10.5594
4   9.85629
7   4.14754
5   5.73541
4   25.081
11  3.85567
5   2.75741
9   5.10188
7   8.81165
4   2.19676
5   14.0147
6   4.66927
15  5.60593
4   21.1329
6   16.578
8   5.60286
4   6.34807
13  11.3636
4   5.06866
7   13.8345
4   8.63026
5   12.6181
7   3.72891
14  11.4156
6   5.65498
4   2.00478
4   6.70047
4   2.74247
7   7.15954
6   6.97321
6   3.06345
7   5.16588
4   1.9815
7   5.71259
4   11.2309
8   13.7251
4   6.49702
17  11.5877
38  2.18001
8   4.10022
50  4.84289
41  12.7175
5   3.99481
39  4.3202
5   9.02036
18  8.49845
14  8.36378
45  7.68327
8   16.1262
47  7.72268
18  1.52906
7   6.55152
23  7.28533
17  7.63679
23  7.1983
20  9.68639
26  2.2919
10  9.31858
6   10.2451
14  10.0946
5   3.35212
13  7.92773
11  7.54864
47  2.69414
10  6.86291
9   5.20244
8   6.42733
4   10.8517
12  3.75473
33  3.27723
6   3.00593
4   15.6508
21  7.96871
12  8.75405
31  12.324
10  1.11662
7   2.15066
24  6.83173
7   3.96771
11  7.5619
4   0.785628
11  14.4666
6   5.11272
5   7.59668
5   9.04664
7   11.9044
5   5.61802
9   11.6637
4   13.5922
4   9.948
18  9.21967
8   11.062
4   14.0495
7   9.60146
47  3.41381
24  5.48075
7   9.34019
4   5.67435
11  3.40312
11  9.22323
37  5.44413
5   22.4815
6   7.20836
6   4.52437
12  10.1285
14  7.16214
20  7.26324
5   20.8528
35  5.39124
4   6.32888
5   7.0733
6   2.41672
21  11.0176
12  3.09272
6   7.32828
5   11.8614
4   13.5878
6   7.44575
37  5.42578
10  16.5581
7   12.1824
20  16.6054
20  18.147
25  4.2557
5   1.51733
4   14.4149
7   7.60474
7   7.05497
13  8.77247
47  7.80778
6   6.32124
5   1.04715
5   8.83554
22  9.06805
18  8.8941
17  2.18289
9   5.88177
9   14.1725
7   8.8699
8   4.18207
12  4.09766
21  8.31261
25  6.74651
21  6.39138
6   6.783
49  2.53901
5   26.7969
16  6.55789
9   17.4564
4   6.49943
5   5.53018
9   6.55773
8   8.22126
17  9.93245
7   10.1271
27  8.38053
4   14.6347
22  5.34149
14  11.3401
7   7.64656
15  4.97067
15  1.49902
7   6.81685
10  14.7443
26  5.19094
4   5.37994
11  9.79944
6   7.01459
8   7.79019
19  11.2786
6   5.355
5   1.26712
9   6.61735
12  7.72715
7   9.55011
67  2.79386
4   2.40071
8   7.30456
46  7.416
9   14.6428
9   7.2112
4   6.63294
7   6.79824
45  2.55119
12  7.82306
5   17.3145
14  11.1806
4   4.08319
7   14.3597
6   3.11201
7   10.0034
8   8.49861
5   11.1623
13  10.6563
6   7.88141
10  13.8632
6   4.04427
13  7.85135
39  5.87709
11  2.46188
25  5.91836
33  10.6482
25  2.37395
21  7.55021
6   6.77897
12  8.32483
7   6.37397
6   14.526
23  4.2424
5   7.73115
4   11.2847
5   13.3916
10  10.1114
5   6.17557
12  8.13141
12  9.6928
17  9.32123
4   3.97583
14  6.00034
9   3.42081
9   12.0713
50  3.79332
15  11.4132
27  5.64309
8   6.7623
7   7.22301
9   12.0606
9   4.29732
15  10.2285
5   17.1166
37  3.41162
6   8.42037
5   3.24976
5   10.4622
6   8.40845
6   1.81865
4   9.25185
23  3.93845
5   21.6799
12  10.6917
16  9.17709
5   31.985
15  17.0313
9   6.52704
7   3.83975
6   2.99867
6   4.39106
21  8.07896
5   6.83469
4   16.8171
6   3.72637
4   4.83495
44  6.07658
22  13.059
6   20.6309
12  4.32898
24  5.63681
4   12.7224
4   27.9618
79  2.83718
25  7.71501
14  7.70377
5   4.41151
10  6.56613
41  3.03904
4   9.90708
4   0.779275
76  4.11521
5   5.35364
10  9.24407
7   2.74147
6   16.4438
6   15.0684
15  2.0893
5   24.5116
5   15.2534
21  3.9638
5   9.42489
34  2.57225
4   7.94264
32  3.59779
8   6.8339
4   1.8738
26  2.59653
4   20.1512
4   3.10731
12  1.38828
4   5.32289
8   2.69905
4   6.26715
7   8.92059
13  4.86136
37  2.38795
5   8.40931
5   10.9193
5   9.2014
7   15.5844
4   10.3963
7   6.36847
16  4.29113
32  5.53641
33  10.2215
8   7.71818
7   14.1442
6   2.99928
4   4.21772
11  6.87553
12  1.34241
18  14.0353
47  2.96704
23  3.70181
7   8.57761
22  6.07572
8   3.50741
43  4.82435
66  6.11313
4   4.73957
14  3.21847
5   6.85557
11  6.90241
4   6.7317
15  2.17576
5   8.61794
5   6.015
4   11.7745
8   1.78445
21  5.67131
4   16.9644
31  0.708555
8   2.1312
16  7.07874
4   8.99811
6   5.80737
82  6.57077
15  9.81252
14  10.0203
11  8.51049
5   4.66913
14  5.1661
28  7.92444
4   4.87349
9   8.18891
4   9.17976
5   2.1189
16  8.0799
6   7.58069
7   4.17751
7   4.41031
13  5.13741
4   2.75857
4   6.82822
4   3.02871
9   13.6115
7   6.33422
7   2.90223
18  8.23854
9   3.79853
6   9.56885
6   9.86923
6   7.31371
6   5.71552
7   4.56533
4   10.0795
46  5.88529
4   18.5347
6   9.14274
9   9.26039
6   8.31048
5   9.35301
7   4.82153
4   3.88126
4   10.8491
4   2.9009
4   7.24601
5   8.66639
5   4.73344
6   5.41322
4   9.48994
14  7.08554
4   9.26597
5   3.9454
4   9.51764
9   4.53588
4   8.6098
7   4.80259
5   3.88361
5   7.41984
9   2.16905
4   6.00152
5   4.41005
19  9.51822
6   7.56169
6   8.70246
10  8.40757
6   5.65566
5   4.26509
21  8.19307
6   5.18222
12  9.12786
4   5.12812
5   14.599
10  5.49054
5   2.03264
6   4.32049
7   2.21361
6   7.26104
5   5.40368
8   2.92935
4   7.79551
4   9.65819
7   8.60384
5   1.68915
7   7.27015
6   6.23645
6   2.48142
11  6.32948
6   2.4595
7   4.95916
11  5.57612
11  4.11866
5   4.14263
10  5.33286
5   4.03639
4   7.61417
8   6.38952
8   4.65564
4   13.087
4   5.47296
4   5.76844
4   2.74936
```

The fit should look like a gamma distribution fit.

Any advice on the code used to create the fit to then plot with ggplot would be a great help. Something like??:

```
function(D) (((n/D)^n)*D^(n-1)*exp(-n*D/D))/(n-1)
```

My current code I have for the distribution plot:

```
p <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = D, y = ..density..),
                 binwidth = 0.5, fill = "grey", color = "black")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the formula represents the probability of finding a molecule at a particular distance *D** after *n* steps, given a diffusion constant *D*. Since *D** is a bit confusing because it could be mixed up with *D*, it has been replaced in the function with *x*. Notice that in the formula, *(n - 1)!* is just the gamma function `gamma(n)`. Therefore, the function in R would be written as:

```
f <- function(x, n, D) (n/D)^n * x^(n-1) * exp(-n * x/D) / gamma(n)
```

The problem we have here is that although the data contains values we can plug in for x and n (df$D and df$n), we don't have the diffusion constant, and in fact this is presumably what you're trying to find here.

However, we can use the above function to give us the sum of the negative log odds of having these data points for any given value of *D*

```
f2 <- function(D) sum(-log(f(df$D, df$n, D)/(1 - f(df$D, df$n, D))))
```

To make things easier, we will vectorize it:

```
f3 <- function(D) sapply(D, f2)
```

This means that if we plot various values for *D*, we can find the maximum likelihood estimate for *D*:

```
plot(0:100, f3(0:100))
```

[image]

And from this it appears that our optimum value of *D* is somewhere between 4 and 9:

```
plot(seq(4, 9, 0.1), f3(seq(4, 9, 0.1)))
```

[image]

and between 7 and 8:

```
plot(seq(7, 8, 0.01), f3(seq(7, 8, 0.01)))
```

[image]

We can find the precise point like this:

```
optimize(f3, range = c(7, 8))
#> $minimum
#> [1] 7.442408

#> $objective
#> [1] 5984.383
```

This means that our best guess for the value of D is 7.442408 according to your data. So we can work out the probability density of finding a molecule at a particular distance for all different values of *n*:

```
n <- c(4:10, 20, 100)
x <- seq(0, 30, 0.1)
dens <- do.call(c, lapply(n, function(i) f(x, i, 7.442408)))

sim <- data.frame(x = rep(x, length(n)), y = dens, n = factor(rep(n, each = 301)))

ggplot(sim, aes(x, y, colour = n)) + geom_line() + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

So we can see that the result is a *family* of gamma distributions which vary according to the number of steps.

To reassure ourselves that we are on the right track here, we can plot the empirical density function of our data points at n == 4 and superimpose our predicted density function:

```r
plot(density(df$D[df$n == 4]), ylim= c(0, 0.2))
lines(sim$x[sim$n == 4], sim$y[sim$n == 4], lty = 2, col = 2)
```

[image]

This looks pretty close.

Comment: Hi Allan, this is exactly the solution. Thank you so much for such a comprehensive answer!

Comment: @Allan_Cameron. The line to simulate the data: sim <- data.frame(x = rep(x, length(n)), y = dens, n = factor(rep(n, each = 301))). The number of rows in dens (15948) is greater than n and x (both 2709), therefore spits out an error.

Comment: @SJH1990 `dens` shouldn't have rows - it's a vector. I have restarted an R session and copied and pasted the code directly from this answer and don't get this error.

Comment: But the vector dens has 'num [1:15948]', so when I try to put it into a data.frame with x and n. I get this error: Error in data.frame(x = rep(x, length(n)), y = dens, n = factor(rep(n,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2709, 15948

Comment: @SJH1990 can you try restarting your R session and importing your data as `df` but NOT attaching it, then copying my exact code from each step of the answer?

Comment: This worked, thanks! No idea why it was generating so many values prior.